# How do I define a random variable involving Part?

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics, list-manipulation

I need to define a random variable that involves `Part`, but when I try, for example

```
vals = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
dist = TransformedDistribution[
  vals[[x + y]], 
  {x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}],
   y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}]
```

I get

> The expression [FormalX]1+[FormalX]2 cannot be used as a part specification.

Comment: Look up `EmpiricalDistribution[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: So I can't use a random variable but to generate a sample?

Comment: I'm telling you that you can build a distribution from `vals`…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Sounds like that could be an answer then.

Comment: Is the goal just to produce RVs, or do you want to use MMA probability functions against the distribution? If the former, `RandomChoice` against the PDF is your friend...

Comment: @ciao: Good point, I do want to use MMA probability functions and need the distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comments, this should fit the bill:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[
   PDF[TransformedDistribution[
      x + y, {x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
       y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}], 
     Range[1, 12]] -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}];

{Mean[dist], Quantile[dist, .5], RandomVariate[dist, 5]}

(*
{65/36,2,{2,2,2,3,2}}
*)
```